# php nginx server got strange header and post data from http request

Tags: php, http, msisdn

Our app server got some strange request, http headers like:

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Content-Length": "3177",
"Host": "xxxxxxxxx",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
"Msisdn": "12345678",
```

And the http post body read using `file_get_contents('php://input')` was beginning with:`ISDN: 12345678\r\n\r\n`

The `Msisdn` entity header and `ISDN: 12345678\r\n\r\n` were not sent by out app client.

Our app written in cpp using libcurl to deal with http request.
I really do not know what has happened now. Especially the `ISDN: 12345678\r\n\r\n` in post body content.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the request came from your application?

Comment: `ISDN` is a mobile phone number, so I think that header is sent by mobile apps.

Comment: Maybe proxy server on the mobile network is adding the header. But it shouldn't modify the post body.

Comment: Not really sure the request came from my application, and out app runs on both iOS and Android, it happened dozens of times a day,

Comment: @Barmar proxy server maybe add headers, but the post body changed too.

Comment: That's completely invalid, but I'm not sure there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: Now i could do nothing at all,  the post body has been cut off, it cannot be properly decoded.

Comment: @zsounder libcurl will not modify your http request by its own accord. Anything your server receives is added either by the client or by some relayer in the network

Comment: there's an interesting discussion here. Would the MSISDN header be set by a network provider if the client was using a mobile phone as a wifi hotspot? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428422/detect-an-msisdn-mobile-number-with-the-browser

Comment: Is the communication happening over HTTP or HTTPS? You should put it on back of HTTPS using Nginx or something and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani its over HTTP

Comment: @UmNyobe agree with you, not a big deal to  add MSISDN header,  but seems the post body changed

Comment: @zsounder, I would suggest you put behind Nginx and protect it using HTTPS and see if that helps. Then may be you wont see such probelms

Comment: @TarunLalwani We can not change to HTTPS for all requests for historic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Clients can add whatever headers they want, as can proxy servers. This header is added in by some mobile networks for all requests.

[Detect an MSISDN (mobile number) with the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428422/detect-an-msisdn-mobile-number-with-the-browser)

Comment: Not a big deal to add MSISDN Or calling-line-id, the thing is the post body had been changed too.

Comment: Then change to HTTPS so the data can't be changed by a MITM proxy on the wireless provider's side.

Comment: We can not change to HTTPS for all requests for historic reasons.

Comment: Then you are accepting that your traffic can be man in the middle'd and altered. And you're exposing every bit of data over this API to being read and modified in transit - which will cause more issues like this in the future.

Your historic reasons will be biting you for the foreseeable future, but thats your project.