# WAP PUSH over SMPP

Tags: sms, push, smpp, wap

Related to [Detect an MSISDN (mobile number) with the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428422/detect-an-msisdn-mobile-number-with-the-browser/58864438?noredirect=1#comment103999469_58864438)

What SMPP parameters should I use for sending WAP PUSH SMS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must set:

```
DATA_CODING = 245 (0xf5)
ESM_CLASS = 64  (0x40)
```

And in PAYLOAD you combine message and wap url following
binary WSP standard:

[WSP Specification](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/release/Browser_Protocol_Stack/V2_1-20050204/OMA-WAP-TS-WSP-V1_0-20020920-C.pdf)

Comment: Hi Marvin, thank you for your answer. What do you refer with "PAYLOAD"? regarding data coding and es_class, I know how using them, but I don't know how to introduce URL.

Comment: In SMPP you can define message as MESSAGE (mandatory) or PAYLOAD (optional tlv field). You encode message and url in binary form following WSP protocol (link above) and that you provide in PAYLOAD field of SMPP.
Example for WSP providing URL you can find here:

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Wireless_Session_Protocol